# Como criar um sistema para listar as imagens mais populares do meu aplicativo

Tags: php, android, mysql

Estou querendo montar um sistema para exibir as imagens mais populares do meu aplicativo.
Hoje eu listo essas imagens de forma simples mas eficiente: as pastas se tornam categorias e listo as imagens de dentro da pasta. Então, o aplicativo lê o link da imagem como url do servidor + categoria + nome da imagem.

Para montar um sistema de popularidade eu pensei em contar quantas vezes alguém clicou no botão de compartilhar e enviar essas informações para um banco MySQL junto da categoria e do nome da imagem. Assim quando eu fazer a listagem em PHP eu posso ordená-las por numero de compartilhamentos.

Alguém pode me ajudar a como fazer isso? Sabem de um projeto open source que tem algo parecido para tentar aprender?

Comment: Você precisa criar um `webservice`, ao clicar em compartilhar, o aplicativo deve enviar o nome(unico) ou `hash` da foto(ou algum identificador unico) para o `webservice` salvar no bd  `mysql` do servidor. No bd precisa ter uma tabela que contém a identificação da foto, categoria e a qtd de compartilhamento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pensei no seguinte:

Você cria uma tabela `compartilhamento`, relacionando `imagem` e `usuario`. A tabela `compartilhamento` seria única nas colunas `imagem_id` e `usuario_id`, fazendo com que nenhum usuário possa compartilhar a imagem mais de uma vez.

A query para buscar as imagens mais compartilhadas seria algo assim:

```
SELECT nome, count(id) compartilhamentos
FROM imagem
GROUP BY nome
ORDER BY compartilhamentos DESC;
```

Em seguida você pode criar um serviço para buscar as imagens mais compartilhadas. A URL desse serviço pode ser algo bem auto-explicativo, algo como:

```
GET /imagens/compartilhadas
```

E a resposta pode ser um XML ou um JSON contendo o resultado da consulta em SQL:

```
[
    {
        "nome": "imagem1.jpg",
        "compartilhamentos": 472
    },
    {
        "nome": "imagem4.jpg",
        "compartilhamentos": 298
    },
    {
        "nome": "imagem5.jpg",
        "compartilhamentos": 112
    },
    {
        "nome": "imagem3.jpg",
        "compartilhamentos": 55
    },
    {
        "nome": "imagem6.jpg",
        "compartilhamentos": 37
    },
    {
        "nome": "imagem2.jpg",
        "compartilhamentos": 14
    }
]
```

PS: dependendo do caso a implementação provavelmente será mais complexa, mas ideia básica é mais ou menos o que foi dito acima.

Comment: Só faltou um `ORDER BY` e um `LIMIT` para pegar as mais compartilhadas :)

Comment: @Lucas bem notado! Coloquei o `ORDER BY` mas o `LIMIT` varia bastante de acordo com a implementação :)